# Can a MFOV Spell Thief spend more than half of their sneak attack dice to steal?

Tags: dnd-5e, homebrew

This question is on the [Spell Thief from Middle Finger of Vecna](http://mfov.magehandpress.com/2016/03/spellthief.html) and their ability to steal spells.

It says the Spell Thief "can forgo half Sneak Attack damage dice (rounded down) to siphon away their arcane energy, you gain a single filled spell slot of the level you are capable of casting and you temporarily learn one spell of your choice that the creature was capable of casting". Does this mean I can use all my sneak attack dice to steal up to the max spell level I can cast?

Comment: Just confirming: This essentially asks if the spell thief can do this *twice* by also forgoing the *other* half of its sneak attack, right?

Answer (score 1):

No, this means that you can forego half your Sneak Attack dice to steal a slot of the level listed in the Spell Level column of the Spellthief table. Their initial wording is a bit confusing, but further down in the entry it says:

> The spell slot you gain with this feature increases in level as you gain levels, as shown in the Spell Level column of the Spellthief Spellcasting Table.

So, when you forego half your Sneak Attack dice to steal a spell, you will always gain a spell slot of the level listed in the table for your current Spellthief level.

Comment: So for example Spell Thief 3 can sack 1/2 their SA dice for Spell that uses a 1st Level Slot so like Mage Armor or Magic Missile. For higher levels like Spell Thief 13 can sack their 1/2 SA dice to for a Spell that uses a 3rd Level Slot to use like Magic Missile 2 Slot Level higher or a Fireball spell?

Comment: @JhyarelleSilver Yep, those are both legit examples.